# git asks me to pull everytime I want to push to my own branch

Tags: git

I have this branch:

local:

```
 bugfix/VMS-172-back-arrow-on-activity-bar
```

remote:

```
origin/bugfix/VMS-172-back-arrow-on-activity-bar
```

So I added my changes locally then pushed it.

Then I made few changes locally again and I pushed it ( I used `git commit --amend` when committing). But this time git asked me to pull before pushing. Why?

My git log:

```
commit f38a4d8828a2fadec3c62c08cc1c90ea66a719bd
Merge: 172968f 642178d
Author: degensharew <degensharew@myCompany.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 15 09:45:59 2015 +0300

    Merge branch 'bugfix/VMS-172-back-arrow-on-activity-bar'
    of myrepository into bugfix/VMS-172-back-arrow-on-activity-bar

    Conflicts:
        vms-mobile/app/src/main/java/AbstractActivity.java

commit 172968f6dcf533e43749986eba95a008c585bbb1
Author: degensharew <degensharew@myCompany.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 14 17:21:01 2015 +0300

    Fixed bug VMS-172.
    Avoided rounded corner style from search view.
    Style back arrow and title of action bar view.
    Disabled 'back action' from activity title. 

commit 642178d27bccbe9ea48c7d8ae123f1c8c01f921f
Author: degensharew <degensharew@myCompany.com>
Date:   Wed Oct 14 17:21:01 2015 +0300

    Fixed bug VMS-172.
    Avoided rounded corner style from search view.
    Style back arrow and title of action bar view.
    Disabled 'back action' from activity title.
```

---

**NB**: I am the only one working on this branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used git commit --amend when committing).But this time git asked me to pull before pushing. Why?

When you used `git commit --amend`, you rewrote the history of the `HEAD` commit in your local branch.  This means that at this point your local and remote branches were diverging from each other.

**Before commit amend:**

```
remote: A <- B <- C
local:  A <- B <- C
```

**After commit amend:**

```
remote: A <- B <- C
local:  A <- B <- C'     (the apostrophe indicates a new commit)
```

You cannot fast forward the remote branch since your local branch has diverged from the remote.  Effectively, your latest commit sits on top of a different base than the remote, and Git is refusing to automatically apply this commit.  The two solutions here would be to *merge* your local branch into the remote, or to *rebase* your local branch on the remote, and then push it in.

As to why you were forced to pull again, this could be for a number of reasons.  For example, if you did another commit amend, this could explain it.  A coworker committing to the same branch could also explain it, but not in your case since you stated you are the only one working this branch.

Comment: Thanks, clean answer.